# Let $f: S^1 \to T$ be an embedding into the torus. $X_f=T \setminus f(S^1)$. Show that $X_f$ is not compact, but it is locally compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $f: S^1 \to T$ be an embedding into the torus (from the circle). We define $X_f=T \setminus f(S^1)$.

> Show that $X_f$ is not compact, but it is locally compact.

---

Context

In question a) we proved that $S^1$ and $T$ are not homeomorphic, since removing two points from the circle leaves it disconnected into two parts, but after removing two points from the torus we see that it is still connected.

In question b) we proved that $f$ is never surjective. This is because an embedding is always a homeomorphism to $f(S^1)$. If $f$ is surjective we get $f(S^1)=T$ and we see that this would imply that $S^1$ and $T$ are homeomorphic. This is a contradiction to a).

---

So we know that $f: S^1 \to T$ is a non-surjective embedding, which means $X_f$ is non-empty, how does this help us with compactness? any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all observe the $T$ is Hausdorff and compact (and so locally compact).

Now if $X_{f}$ were to be compact, it would be closed because compact sets of Hausdorff spaces are closed. So we would have that $T\backslash X_{f} = f(S^{1})$ is open as it is the complement of a closed set. Now $f(S^{1})$ is compact because $S^{1}$ is and $f$ is continuous, so $f(S^{1})$ must be closed too. We just proved that $f(S^{1})$ is both open and closed, but this is impossible in a connected space such as $T$. So $X_{f}$ is not compact.
Now to prove locally compactness: we already know (by the previous argument) that $f(S^{1})$ is closed, so $X_{f}\subset T$ is open, and an open subspace of a locally compact Hausdorff space ($T$ is one of those) is againg locally compact.

If anything of what I said is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: It seems that we actually do not need to use that $f$ is not-surjective. In your notation $T_f=X_f$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $X_{f}$, I'll edit. Actually if $f$ was indeed surjective, you'd have $X_{f} = \emptyset$ which is compact.

Comment: Your argument is logical, it is amazing to see how everything just clicks into place, but I am not at the level yet that I can completely construct such an argument myself. I will have an exam in about a month so there is still plenty of time to practice, thank you for your help. This was instructive.

Comment: Maybe you have not yet encountered some of the theorems I used in the proof, so it's completely normal to feel a bit dazzled. After a while reading proofs, studying theorems and try proving something yourself it becomes easier and easier. Practice makes perfect. I remember my first exam of General Topolgy and I felt exactly like you. Good luck with your exam!

Comment: Thank you for your encouraging words.